# find numbers with fix length in text file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file which does not have any specific format. It contains text and numbers. I want to get numbers only with 24 digits. **I want to remove all extra text and get those numbers separated by space or newline**.

I can select numbers with 24 digits by using `[0-9]{24}` but I want to remove all extra text and leave the numbers there.

For example, if the file is like this:

```
asafa sfasd asd 123 15 1 asd ad7a sd78a6s da87ds6a 8s7d .123 1.
32 141.23 . 123456789012345678901234 asafa sfasd asd 123 15 1 asd ad7a sd78a6s da87ds6
a 8s7d .123 1.32 141.23 . 123456789012345678901234 asafa sfasd asd 123 15 1 asd ad7a sd78a6s da87ds6a 8s7d .12
3 1.32 141.23 . 123456789012345678901234 asafa sfasd asd 123 15 1 asd ad7a sd78a6s da87ds6a 8s7d .123 1.32 141.23 . 123456789012345678901234
```

I want to get

```
123456789012345678901234 123456789012345678901234 123456789012345678901234 123456789012345678901234
```

separated by space or newline (any separator would do.) Numbers are not always the same in the file, this is just an example to show what I'm going to do.

Thanks.

Comment: To select numbers \d{24}

Comment: Why are you downvoting?

Comment: It was not me who downvoted else I would have written the reason for downvoting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the following regex and replace with an empty string:

```
(?>(?:\D|(?<!\d)\d{1,23}(?!\d)|(?<!\d)\d{25,}(?!\d))+)
```

It will match all text that is not digits, or numbers that are not 24 symbols long.

Settings screen:

[image]

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `(?>...)` - An atomic group syntax, we do not backtrack inside the group (it increases performance)
- `(?:\D|(?<!\d)\d{1,23}(?!\d)|(?<!\d)\d{25,}(?!\d))+` - A non-capturing group where we list our alternatives (the patterns we want to match) that are listed with `|` alternation operator:

  - `\D` - a non-digit
  - `(?<!\d)\d{1,23}(?!\d)` - Any sequence of 1 to 23 digits that are not preceded with a digit (thanks to the negative look-behind `(?<!\d)`), and are not followed by a digit (thanks to the negative look-ahead `(?!\d)`)
  - `(?<!\d)\d{25,}(?!\d)` - A similar to the above, but it matches sequences of 25 digits and more.

Comment: Just a note: in your sample input text, `1234567889012345678901234` has doubled `8`. If you remove one `8`, it will work. And +1 from me for a nice riddle.

Comment: Thanks alot, It worked, can you please explain whats happening inside that regex?

Comment: I have added the regex explanation. Atomic group is not necessary, but it reduces overhead, and decreases the probability of catastrophic backtracking.